# State machine with node.js for mmo game

Tags: node.js, backend, game-development, state-machine, mmo

I have a couple of questions about the state machine on back-end(node.js).
I am making an mmo game and I want to use finite state machine in the backend. The server communicates with the client via UDP with JSON. (On the client have self-written state machine)
Which pattern is best for mmo game server?I will be glad if you provide links to the documentation.
I found out that there is an "Xstate" library. But I'm not sure how good it is on node.js. Has anyone had experience with it?